# Can be wordpress configured as a touristic portal?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I need to develop a touristic portal that should have basically articles about tourist attractions, accommodations, restaurants. Articles must have pictures, videos, comments.
I also need twitter, facebook integration.

Can wordpress be used for this? I used Drupal cms before ... but I heard that WordPress is more user friendly and it is very seo friendly.

Do you think that this is a good solution?

Comment: This is perhaps a better question for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, WordPress is highly customizable CMS, with loads of additional content to be found on web.
[Here you can find some books, I'm sure you'll find something for you](http://www.netchunks.com/25-best-books-for-wordpress-bloggers/)

Also there is a bunch of tutorials on net so book isn't necessary. Just google a bit ;) 
Also, you may consider using joomla, do some research on both and select the most suitable one

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is basically a blogging platform. Therefore it would be quite difficult to customize it for a touristic portal.

It is indeed very SEO friendly, but the backend should be a little too simple for that mass of content. Just think about all the categories (countries, cities, attractions)...

I feel drupal or typo3 would be more suited for such a project...

Comment: Since Wordpress 3.0 you can define your custom content types just like in Drupal. I believe this could be done with WordPress, absolutely. But I, as Maximilian, believe that Drupal would be a better fit.